# numberOfRowsInSection: not called on reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that uses an array to list data. This works fine.
I also have an `UISearchBar` for searching in that `tableview`. When data is matched in the tableviews array those rows are added to another mutable array, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` displays data from that mutable array instead.

But `numberOfRowsInSection:` is never called when I call reloadData. Therefore the `tableview` crashes when scrolling, because it's trying to get data from the mutable array, but for rows that are in the original array (which has more items)

I've debugged for quite a while now, but can not for the love of god find the reasons for this. Datasource and Delegate are hooked up in the `tableview`, because it can show the data from the original array.

```c
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
         NSLog(@"isSearching: %d", isSearching);
         // Return the number of rows in the section.
         if(!isSearching)
            return [originalArray count];

         NSLog(@"isSearching - Return searchCopyListOfItems");
         return [searchCopyListOfItems count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         if(cell == nil) {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         }

         if(!searching)
             cell.textLabel.text = [originalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         else
             cell.textLabel.text = [searchCopyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Check if the table has memory when you are reloading it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how you reload your table?
doing `[table relaodData];` right?
is your table is connected to IBOutlet on your nib?
at the point of reloading , is `table` initialized?

you can post crash info too.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Somehow, IB had disconnected the IBOutlet to the UITableView in the xib. I didn't notice it wasn't connected because the original data was shown successfully. However, in hindsight I realize this is not because of the referencing outlet, but because of the delegate and datasource connections

Comment: I did the same mistake, I forgot to connect the datasource outlet to the view controller.

Answer (score 17):

if `numberOfSections` returns `0`, `numberOfRowsInSection` will not be called.

Comment: This was it for me! TYVM

Answer (score 10):

Be sure not to call `reloadData` from within any of the table view's delegate methods. This will cause unpredictable behavior. Also, make sure you did not call `beginUpdates` before, and that you only call your `reloadData` method from the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding `beginUpdates`!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today with XCode 6.1

In my code, I had the `dataSource` and `delegate` set:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

...and strangely, my code *would* populate the table when it first loaded... but it then ignored any calls to `reloadData`.

In the Storyboard, when I right-clicked on the Table View in the Storyboard, it's "outlet" radio button was an empty circle.

I dragged a line from this empty circle to the parent `UIView`, and *then* the `reloadData` did work okay.

[image]

Somehow, I had lost the `IBOutlet` link between my UITableView control and the .h/.m files used to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just also make sure you're not moving the table in the process of reloading data cause it might call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` while you're still updating your data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the stubbed-out number of sections returned 0, and even though I wasn't planning to use sections, there's got to be 1 as it's higher in the object hierarchy than rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26632808/1449799

Answer (score 0):

For me, the gotcha was that I was attempting to increment a value *and* return it from `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

i.e. `return someValue++`

Apparently this isn't possible, and in my case, it wasn't incrementing `someValue` from 0 to 1, and so returning 0 sections, hence there was no reason for the `numberOfRowsInSection:` to be called!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was that I'd copy-pasted it from another nib and forgotten to rewire the `dataSource` and `delegate` outlets in IB. This has happened to me before but I thought I'd post it here in case this solution helps some who come across this problem.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```