# SWIFT ALAssetsLibrary not enumerating groups

Tags: ios, swift, closures, enumeration, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to gather thumbnails of all the user's images into an array, but when I call the `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock` method of `ALAssetsLibrary` nothing seems to happen.

```
import UIKit
import AssetsLibrary

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {


@IBOutlet var photoLibView: UICollectionView
var assetLibrary : ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()


func showCustomLibrary() {
    self.assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()

    var assetsArray : [ALAsset] = []
    var imageArray : [CGImage] = []
    var count = 0
    var countOne = 0
    let assetsType : ALAssetsGroupType = Int(ALAssetsGroupAll)

    var groupBlock : ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock = {

        (group: ALAssetsGroup!, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) in
        println("is goin")
        count++
        var assetBlock : ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock = {
            (result: ALAsset!, index: Int, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) in
            imageArray.append(result.thumbnail().takeRetainedValue())
            assetsArray.append(result)
            countOne++
        }

        group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock(assetBlock)


    }
    var groupFailureBlock : ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock = {
        (NSError) in
        println("errorrrrrrrr")

    }
    assetLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(assetsType, usingBlock: groupBlock, failureBlock: groupFailureBlock)



    println("number of groups")
    println(count)
    println("number of total assets")
    println(countOne)

    self.photoLibView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(imageArray)


}


}
```

When I run showCustomLibrary() is called, the compiler prints `number of groups
0
number of total assets
0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

because it seems as though the groups of the `ALAssetsLibrary` are not being enumerated. ("is goin" is not being printed). Any idea what's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.
In this "group" and result should not be nil other wise it crash in swift.
So we should check for nil case
Like

```
var groupBlock : ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock = {

    (group: ALAssetsGroup!, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) in
    println("is goin")
    if group != nil
    {
        count++
         var assetBlock : ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock = {
            (result: ALAsset!, index: Int, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) in
            if result != nil
            {
             imageArray.append(result.thumbnail().takeRetainedValue())
             assetsArray.append(result)
             countOne++
            }
        }
    }

    group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock(assetBlock)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the stubbed out code was returning 0 for the number of sections, so i changed it to 1 at least for the example i was working on: https://github.com/thegreatmichael/Albums-iOS8-Swift/blob/master/Albums/IAAlbumsViewController.swift#L66